# Fetching all guild members [djs11]

Tags: discord.js

I was wondering is it possible to fetch through all members in the guild and get their IDs?

I made something like

```
msg.guild.members.forEach(guildMember => {
              guildMember.fetchMembers().then(console.log(guildMember.id))
          })
```

But I got an error so I guess I did it in

```
TypeError: guildMember.fetchMembers is not a function
```

Also, I am using discord v11

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply console log all user IDs like this:

```js
msg.guild.members.forEach(guildMember => {
      console.log(guildMember.user.id);
    })
```

Comment: Hmm, but for larger guilds, I'll have to fetch members

Comment: Like I only get 4-6 IDs but there are 300+ people in the guild

Comment: Hm okay I get all 286 IDs from my server with this code

Comment: Amm, I have no idea

Comment: Maybe you should update to discord.js v12

Comment: I like v11 :v, but i might in future